# Moving site from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: redirect, ssl, https, http

I've been told to move a site from HTTP to HTTPS. After the hosting said that they installed the SSL certificate, I thought all I had to do was to simply change the site URL from HTTP to HTTPS, but then the site is not accessible. Do I also have to change the Wordpress URL? I'm wary of doing so as it cause a site to be completely unaccessible as this changes values in the database I suppose. Should changing the site URL from HTTP to HTTPS all the necessary? If that doesn't work, it means the SSL certificate is not installed properly?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a webhosting error. Specifically, the webserver settings error.
I vote not to switch to HTTPS :)

This may be a certificate setting error (not a wrong certificate itself) or routing for HTTPS requests.

Comment: The certificate passes all the tests now but the https appears crossed out in red.

Comment: Can You paste a link to site (page)?

Comment: Did you change the site URL and home URL? Check in the wp-config.php file too